# jQuery cookie setting its own path ignoring statement {path: ''}

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using `Kendo PanelBar` with an event for selecting items where
I set a cookie like this:

```
function panelBarSelect(e) {
...
    $.cookie("panelBarSelection", dataItem.text, {path: 'myAdmin'});
...
}
```

where dataItem.text holds the value of the span text within a panelbar list element.
So I remember the last selection of the `PanelBar`.

However - some how I find myself suddenly having muliple `cookies` with this name **panelBarSelection**, but with a path !=*'myAdmin'*

How come?

edit:
also not working:

```
     $.cookie("panelBarSelection", dataItem.text, {path: ''});
 $.cookie("panelBarSelection", dataItem.text, {path: null});
 $.cookie("panelBarSelection", dataItem.text, {path: '/'});
 $.cookie("panelBarSelection", dataItem.text, {path: 'iGiveUp'});
```

Comment: really? no one? this totally breaks all my code. there has to be an explanation for this behaviour and this should cause a lot of problems!?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution using pure **JS**:

```
 var cookieName = 'panelBarSelection';
            var cookieValue = dataItem.text;
            document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + ";domain=localhost;path=/";
```

**interesting:**
the jQuery equivalent still does not work:

```
$.cookie("panelBarSelection", dataItem.text, {domain: "localhost",path: "/"});
```

unfortunately this makes testing difficult as the `domain` would be **localhost**

Comment: Try without domain :
$.cookie("panelBarSelection", dataItem.text, {path: "/"});

Comment: Any value for path will be overwritten